# Package Marketing Cloud Install Failed

Tags: marketing-cloud-connect, professional-edition

When I go to install the Marketing Cloud Connect package in Salesforce. I get the following error message in an email. The list of Invalid types goes on for about 60 items

```
Your request to install package "Marketing Cloud Marketing Cloud" was unsuccessful. None of the data or setup information in your salesforce.com organization was affected.

If your install continues to fail, contact Salesforce CRM Support through your normal channels and provide the following information.

Organization: xxxxxxx (00D00000000)
User: xxxxxxxx (0000000000000)
Package: Marketing Cloud (000000000) Error Number: 637880228-39581 (1068844765)
Problem:

1.  Invalid type: CampaignMemberChangeEvent
Test_JBIntCDCEventManager: Invalid type: CampaignMemberChangeEvent

2.  Invalid type: CampaignMemberChangeEvent
Test_JBIntCDCEventManager: Invalid type: CampaignMemberChangeEvent
```

I have looked at the below help article here and I do in fact have Platform events enabled.
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000320808&type=1&mode=1